# Loop through 2 arrays at the same time in an ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have two array's that I'm returning from my controller like so:

```
@array1 = []
@array2 = []

@person_stat = PersonStats.select("id").map(&:id)

for idx in 0 ... @person_stat.size
  @array1[idx] = Person.find(@person_stat[idx])
  @array2[idx] = Array2.id_to_array2(@array[idx].id)
end

return @array1, @array2
```

But now I need to print a table in in my `.html.erb` file. My guess was:

```
<%= @array1.each, @array2.each do |a1, a2| %>
<tr><td><%= a1.name %></td><td><%= a2.type %></td></tr>
<% end %>
```

But that is not correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are they always the same size?

Comment: Yes they are always the same size.

Comment: This is too much logic/thought in the view layer. Zip them in the controller, presenter, decorator, helper, anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The more ruby-stic approach is to use the [zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-zip) function:

```
a = (1..10).to_a
b = (10..20).to_a

a.zip(b).each do |c, d|
  puts "#{c}, #{d}"
end
```

In your case:

```
<%= @array1.zip(@array2) do |a1, a2| %>
<tr><td><%= a1.name %></td><td><%= a2.type %></td></tr>
<% end %>
```